# Syntax error in FROM clause vb.net

Tags: syntax-error, vb.net-2010, oledbconnection

Just to let you know this is my first question im posting on this website, so please if I've missed anything just let me know. The problem im having is this, when the program runs im getting the following error message

Syntax error in FROM clause

The code is here

```
    Dim dbProvider As String
    Dim dbSource As String
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim MaxRows As Integer
    Dim sql As String
    Dim TableName As String
    Dim TableCreate As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("CREATE TABLE [" & TableName & "](" & "ID INTEGER NOT NULL," & ")", con)
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM  [" & TableName & "]", con)
    Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)

    TableName = TbTableName.Text

    dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
    dbSource = "Data Source = E:\A2 Computing\Project\PasswordDatabase.mdb"

    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

    con.Open()

    da.Fill(ds, "NewTable")

    MaxRows = ds.Tables("NewTable").Rows.Count
```

The Problem im having is at this line

```
    da.Fill(ds, "NewTable")
```

Im not sure what I've missed out, Im guessing its something to do with the brackets when I declare tablecreate or da? =S Any help would be greatly appreciated. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign something to `TableName` *before* you use it, not after. Your current SQL is `SELECT * FROM []`, which is why you're getting a syntax error there.

Change the order of your code:

```
Dim TableName As String
TableName = TbTableName.Text

Dim TableCreate As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("CREATE TABLE [" & TableName & "](" & _
   "ID INTEGER NOT NULL" & ")", con)
Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM  [" & TableName & "]", con)
Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
```

You also need to execute the `TableCreate` statement. IIRC, you use `ExecuteNonQuery` to do so.

```
TableCreate.ExecuteNonQuery;
```

Your table create SQL could be simplified, BTW:

```
' Remove unnecessary concatenation for column definition, as it's always
' the same
Dim TableCreate As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("CREATE TABLE [" & TableName & _
  "](ID INTEGER NOT NULL)", con)
```

Where are you actually connecting to the database? I don't see an `OleDBConnection` anywhere in your code?

Here's a full example from the MSDN documentation for [OleDBCommand.ExecuteNonScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery.aspx):

```
Private Sub CreateOleDbCommand( _
      ByVal queryString As String, ByVal connectionString As String)
  Using connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    connection.Open()
    Dim command As New OleDbCommand(queryString, connection)
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
  End Using
End Sub
```

Also, you are aware that doing a `CREATE TABLE` creates a new, empty table, and therefore your `SELECT * FROM` it won't return anything but a single `NULL` row because you're not inserting any data?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I have tried your suggestion, and it has worked! However I have run into another problem, namely this


The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot find the input table or query 'AwesomeTable'.  Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly.


It seems that I haven't actually created the table yet, and im not sure of what statement to use how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for this, I have tried the code you have given me, and I do have an OLEDB connection however in my copy and paste haste I left it behind, as you might have guessed I have called it _con_. The new error message is **Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement.** It comes up at the `Tablecreate.Executenonquery` line Im not sure where I have gone wrong but again I suspect its something to do with the brackets. Thank you again for all your help so far

Comment: Since you're not providing any info on what you're putting into `TableName`, it's extremely difficult to help you any further. What database are you using? I just tested `CREATE TABLE [temptable](ID INTEGER NOT NULL)` using SQL Server Management Studio (SQL Server Express), and it worked perfectly. Try placing a `MsgBox` just before the `ExecuteNonQuery` and showing the `TableCreate.CommandText`; what **exactly** does it contain at that point?

Comment: Apologies, Im using Microsoft Access, it was due to my clumsiness that the last error came up, I hadn't moved the `Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM  [" & TableName & "]", con)` line to the correct place yet before I ran the code, and now the error message is different, **Syntax error in field definition.** is what im getting from the same line now. All im putting into `tablename` is some times and subject names from within vb if thats what you mean? The result from the msgbox is `CREATE TABLE [TestTable](ID INTEGER NOT NULL,)` Thanks Again =)

Comment: Remove the comma after `NULL` and before the closing paren (eg., `(ID INTEGER NOT NULL)` instead. Also, if this solves your problem, you should accept it to indicate to others that you've found the answer you need.

Comment: Ahh thank you so much! All that hassle down to a comma. Ill mark the question as Answered, thanks again!